# Trying to make menu separator dashes instead of solid

Tags: html, css, menu

Trying to make menu separators dashes instead of solid lines. I know the dashed code but don't want it to go all the way from the top of the top bar to the bottom, so just in the middle if that makes since example is like the menu here: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/industrial-and-engineering/full_screen_preview/19013654?_ga=2.241886977.2083560788.1554387032-1316791551.1554387032 My website is: http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/ thanks! :)

border-left: 1px dashed #696969;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>Horizontal Navigation Bar w/Rollover Effect</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 

#navbar ul { 
  height: inherit;
  /* margin: 0; REMOVE THIS*/
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Suggested */
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right; 
  background-color: #000; 
} 

/* Suggested for aesthetic reasons */
#navbar {
  background-color: #000;
}

#navbar ul li {  
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 10px 4px;
  height: inherit;
  border-left: 1px solid #696969;
    } 

#navbar ul li a { 
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    text-decoration: bold; 
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    color: #fff; 
/*     background-color: #000;  */
    } 

#navbar ul li:hover { 
    background-color: #000; 
    } 
#navbar ul li:hover a { 
    color: #fff !important; 
    } 
#navbar { background-color: #000; }
    #navbar{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000; /*To bring the navbar to the top of the stacking context*/
    width: 100%;
    }
    nav.stricky-fixed.fadeInDown.animated{

   top:40px; /*Since this element is already set as relative in the original code,
              the top property places the slideIn menu 40px (height of black nav menu)
              from the top of the page.*/

  }

.social-icon-wrapper:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: 1px solid #696969;
}
    .social-icon-wrapper:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.social-icon {
  width: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

 .submit-btn {
  background-color: green !important;
  border-left: 1px solid #696969 !important;
  border-right: 1px solid #696969 !important;
  }
--> 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<!--  -->
<div id="navbar"> 
  <ul class="container"> 
      <ul>
        <li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/tonPA8V.png"></a></li><!--  --><li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/fEvitJl.png"></a></li><!--  --><li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/UiwMSrt.png"></a></li><!--  --><li><a href="mailto:project@stephensengineering.com">project@stephensengineering.com</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="tel:+18883000642">888-300-0642</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/stephens-university/">Stephens University</a></li><!--  --><li class="submit-btn" ><a href="http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/submit-assignment/">Submit Assignment</a></li> 
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Remove `border-left:1px dashed #696969` in `#navbar ul li` class and add this css in `#navbar ul li a` class like below:

```
#navbar ul li a { 
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    text-decoration: bold; 
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    color: #fff; 
    border-left:1px dashed #696969
} 
.social-icon-wrapper:nth-child(3) a {
    border-right: 1px dashed #696969;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped, but no my social media icons are not centered between the separators. Is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: Welcome. Give `vertical-align:middle` instead of `top` to `social-icon` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just changes code as following in your css file.

```css
#navbar ul li {
  border-left: 1px dashed #696969;
}
.social-icon-wrapper:nth-child(3) {
  border-left: 1px dashed #696969;
}
```

Comment: This will make the dashed line go from top to bottom. What @MercedesPennel *don't* want. ```#navbar ul li a``` will target the element with padding so it won't reach to the top and bottom.